# How to restrict user to select only one item from the item list in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working In Ionic App and I have shown the item list in which I have the checkbox for the item selection. User can select only one item but the problem is that, In my item list user is able to select all items.

This is my **shopping.html**:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let itm of shippingdetails">
          <ion-item-divider>
            <ion-checkbox slot="end" [disabled]="isCheckboxDisabled" (ionChange)="selectCP(itm)"></ion-checkbox>
            <!-- <ion-radio slot="start"></ion-radio> -->
            <!-- <ion-toggle slot="start"></ion-toggle> -->
            <ion-label>
            <h2>{{itm.name}}</h2>
            <p>{{itm.mobile}}</p>
            <p>{{itm.state}}, {{itm.city}}</p>
            <p>{{itm.address}}</p>
            <p>Pincode: {{itm.pincode}}</p>
            </ion-label>
            <button ion-button outline item-end>
              <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button ion-button outline item-end>
              <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-item-divider>
</ion-list>
```

In this, I am showing the check-boxes with the items where user can select the item.

This is my **shopping.ts**:

```
isCheckboxDisabled:boolean=false;
selectCP(itm){

}
```

I am not able to make the logic for that. In my html, user can select all the items. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [ion-radio](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/radio/) instead.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-radio-group>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let itm of shippingdetails">
      <ion-label>{{itm.name}}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="{{itm.id}}"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```